# JSON.parse() problem with regular expression values

Tags: javascript, regex, json, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following JSON string, encoded with PHP 5.2 json_encode():

```
{"foo":"\\."}
```

This JSON string is valid. You can check it out at http://www.jsonlint.com/

But the native JSON.parse() method (Chrome, Firefox), throws the following error, while parsing:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Does anybody of you know, why I cannot parse escaped regular expression meta chars?

This example works:

```
{"foo":"\\bar"}
```

But this one fails also:

```
{"foo":"\\?"}
```

BTW: `\.` is just a simple test regular expression, which I want to run via javascript's RegExp object.

Thanks for your support,

Dyvor

Comment: It works for `'{"foo":"\\\\?"}'`. So it seems you have to "double escape" the characters. `'{"foo":"\\bar"}'` **seems** to work (it throws no error) but the result will be `{foo: "ar"}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's "not working" because you're missing a key point: there are **two** string parses going on when you type into the Chrome console a line like:

```
JSON.parse('{"foo": "\\."}');
```

The **first** string parse happens when the JavaScript interpreter parses the string constant you're passing in to the "parse()" method.  The **second** string parse happens inside the JSON parser itself.  After the first pass, the double-backslash is just a single backslash.

This one:

```
{"foo":"\\bar"}
```

works because "\b" is a valid intra-string escape sequence.

Comment: +1  Pointy's right
var test = {"foo":"\\bar"};
alert(JSON.stringify(test));
// alerts '{"foo":"\\bar"}';

var test2 = '{"foo":"\\bar"}';
alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(test2)));
// alerts '{"foo":"\bar"}';

Comment: @DefyGravity I don't understand what you're getting at there. -- oh OK :-)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me in the firebug console.

```
>>> JSON.parse('"\\\\."');
"\."
```

which is correct as the json parser actually receives `"\\."`, i.e. an esacped backslashes and a dot.

Did the problem actually happend to you with the response coming from PHP? Or just in a "manual" test?

Answer (score 0):

add an extra set of \\, as to why it works I'm not exactly sure.

```
JSON.parse('{"foo":"\\\\."}');
```

Comment: It works because there are two parses happening: the JavaScript parse of the string constant coded into the function call expression, and then the JSON parse of the resulting string.