# JSON string could not convert to array/ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, gson

```
[
    {
        countryCode: "CN",
        countryCallingCode: "+86",
        codeRule: "^1\d{10}$"
    },
    {
        countryCode: "US",
        countryCallingCode: "+1",
        codeRule: "^\d{10}$"
    }
]
```

So I define the model like this in Kotlin

```
data class CountryCallingCode(
        val countryCode: String,
        val countryCallingCode: String,
        val codeRule: String? = null
)
```

This is what the backend document defines the response.
codeRule is regex expression to verify a phone number.

I stuck in convert the String to List.

I pasted them to Android Studio, and it shows like:

```
String response = "[\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        countryCode: \"CN\",\n" +
        "        countryCallingCode: \"+86\",\n" +
        //"        codeRule: \"^1\\d{10}$\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        countryCode: \"US\",\n" +
        "        countryCallingCode: \"+1\",\n" +
        //"        codeRule: \"^\\d{10}$\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "]";
```

The following codes do not work.

Converting code 1:

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
CountryCallingCode[] countryCallingCodeList = gson.fromJson(response, CountryCallingCode[].class);
```

And I think the following codes are the same, correct me if I am wrong.

Converting code 2:

```
ArrayList<CountryCallingCode> countryCallingCodeList = (ArrayList<CountryCallingCode>)gson.fromJson(response, ArrayList.class);
```

Converting Code 3

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<CountryCallingCode>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<CountryCallingCode> countryCallingCodeList = gson.fromJson(response, type);
```

Then I use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to reformat my json.

[image: JsonString with codeRule online check error]
[image: JsonString without codeRule online check error]

I tried to remove the codeRule, and pasted to the Android Studio, it also tells me I am wrong, it shows CountryCode causes SyntaxException.

```
    String reponse = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        countryCode: \"CN\",\n" +
            "        countryCallingCode: \"+86\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        countryCode: \"US\",\n" +
            "        countryCallingCode: \"+1\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]";
```

Only I compress the jsonstring to oneline, I could convert the jsonstring to the array/ArrayList.

```
String response = "[{\"countryCode\":\"CN\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+86\"},{\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+1\"}]";
```

Does anyone know

- Q1:

How to deal with codeRule?

- Q2:

Why couldn't I pasted the origin JsonString to the Android Studio?

Why I must compress the JsonString into one line string?

Updated:

Origin one line json string:

```
[{"countryCode":"CN","countryCallingCode":"+86", codeRule: "^1\d{10}$"},{"countryCode":"US","countryCallingCode":"+1", codeRule: "^\d{10}$"}]
```

Pasted result json string:

```
String response = "[{\"countryCode\":\"CN\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+86\", codeRule: \"^1\\d{10}$\"},{\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+1\", codeRule: \"^\\d{10}$\"}]";
```

Code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

/* Convertion 1 */
CountryCallingCode[] countryCallingCodeList = gson.fromJson(response, CountryCallingCode[].class);
```

Error:

```
result = {JsonSyntaxException@7237} Method threw 'com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException' exception.
 cause = {MalformedJsonException@7241} "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 65 path $[0].codeRule"
 detailMessage = "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Invalid escape sequence at line 1 column 65 path $[0].codeRule"
 stackState = null
 stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[28]@7243} 
 suppressedExceptions = {Collections$EmptyList@7244}  size = 0
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@1694} "class com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2082115852
```

Comment: A1: I believe its an issue with parsing regexes [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221026/json-parse-problem-with-regular-expression-values)    A2: When pasting it directly, android studio added characters which should not be included in a json. It does that to keep the source formatting, which you actually don't want. The JSON format has no spaces and no `\n`, unless they are included in a string value

Comment: A completely valid JSON, wraps the field names in quotes as well: `[  
   {  
      "countryCode":"CN",
      "countryCallingCode":"+86",
      "codeRule":"^1\\d{10}$"
   }
]`

Comment: I am not sure why you get `codeRule` without the quotes, but that is your issue left

Comment: @XtremeBaumer

Thanks, I could run and get the list when the response is 

```val response = "[{\"countryCode\":\"CN\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+86\",\"codeRule\":\"^1\\\\d{10}$\"},{\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"countryCallingCode\":\"+1\",\"codeRule\":\"^\\\\d{10}$\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I need more space to explain - if your version of Java supports it, can you try creating your response with a raw string like this:

```
String response = `[
    {
        countryCode: "CN",
        countryCallingCode: "+86",
        codeRule: "^1\d{10}$"
    },
    {
        countryCode: "US",
        countryCallingCode: "+1",
        codeRule: "^\d{10}$"
    }
]`
```

Or if possible use Kotlin, which uses `"""` to delimit raw strings. It will be much more readable and might help you spot mistakes

Comment: How to create my response with a raw string like this?Do I need to type it manually?

Comment: ' ' is not allowed for both Java and Kotlin, could you gave me a buildable codes?